# Missing private key iphone developer in keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to run an application on my iPhone, but I'm having problems with the code signing identity.
Actually I have two certificate in my keychains, one for the distribution, and one for developing that does not have the private key.
I tried to download again the certificate from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) but I still can't have the private key.
In fact I can't select the iPhone developer profile from *Target -> Build settings -> Code signing Identity* because I get the error:

> Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in your
>   keychains.

Moreover in the organizer the status of the developer profile is:

> Valid signing identity not found.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Private key will be in the machine from which Cert has been requested. Export it from keychain from that machine and import it on yours.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see it in my keychains, can you help me? If you want I can send you some screenshot

Comment: are you publishing this app for the first time? are you working on different machine?

Answer (score 25):

If you had an older machine where you had created a CSR and downloaded the certificate originally, then export the certificate from its keychain. Save it as a .p12 file and then copy it to your new machine on which you are working currently. Double click the .p12 file to install it to your keychain. Expand and see if you see the private key.

If this is the original machine and you still do not have a private key in your keychain, you would have to request for a new certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no this is the machine where I'm used to work.
http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1840/14q1.png
This is a screenshot of my keychains

Comment: You will have to request for a new development certificate at developer.apple.com/iphone from your developer program and then download and install it in order to get a certificate with a private key.

Comment: But do I need to revoke the old ones? Or I can just create a new one?

Comment: I do know that earlier Apple allowed just 1 certificate to be available at a time. If that's the case, you may have to revoke the old one and create a new one. Logon to developer.apple.com/iphone to your developer program and check once. I believe, now they do let you create a new certificate without revoking old one.

Comment: Thank you, I had to revoke the old one and create a new dev certificate. Now when I try to run my app I get: Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer: Barbara Strada (YFJG3T6CR3)' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.
But that certificate appears just once...
http://postimg.org/image/qjlz8npnb/
Do you have any suggest?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have your private key in your keychain or stored anywhere else, then you cannot sign an app.
There is no point in downloading the developer certificate from Apple. Your private key is NEVER sent to Apple at any point in the process. Only your public key is sent.

The private key & public key PAIR is created when you create a Certificate Signing Request using keychain. This is exactly what you need to do if you have lost your private key.

Answer (score 2):

We identified in our case that we were exporting the WRONG certificate, because Keychain Access has a UX deficiency in that when you use the search box, you don't see certificates with a name matching what you searched for, you see certificates tied to PRIVATE KEYS with a name that matches what you searched for.

Because of this confusing UX of Keychain access, we were continually exporting the wrong certificate (but had convinced ourselves it was right because the name matched). Once we identified it as the right certificate, our import problem & signing identity missing private keys messages went away

see [Can't import Code-signing Public or Private keys using Keychain access (Mac OS X Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543198/cant-import-code-signing-public-or-private-keys-using-keychain-access-mac-os-x) for complete notes.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too recently. No proper reason as to why it did happen. I had tried revoking the certificate as well. But no help. So I created a new certificate.

This might help
http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2013/09/ios-code-sign-in-complete-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in your keychains.
```

This particular error can occur for couple of reasons, but the most commons are -

1. The certificate you have installed in your keychain is not the one with which you created your provisioning profile, Remember, you had to select a certificate when you created the profile?
2. The certificate that you used to create the provisioning profile is either revoked or expired.