# problems code signing adhoc or for app store

Tags: xcode, key, keychain, certificate

Here is what I believe is a related question:

[Can't import Code-signing Public or Private keys using Keychain access (Mac OS X Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543198/cant-import-code-signing-public-or-private-keys-using-keychain-access-mac-os-x/24746620#24746620)

---

I have a similar problem where both the AdHoc profile "valid signing identity not found". When I try to generate an app store image, I get a slightly more detailed message that the private key for the profile cannot be found. It is unclear however, if this is the developer cert or the distro cert.

The keychain app shows the cert installed and pub/priv keys listed for the distro certificate, but not for the developer.

In the app store I tried creating a new distro cert, and eventually revoked it, but on a page refresh it re-appears. There is some limit that only one distro cert can be active, and I have the feeling this too can interfere with the signing validity chain.

---

Revocation of the newer distro cert seems to have stuck, but the problem remains.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to revoke my developer cert to clear the problem. The distro cert was probably fine, because revoking the distro cert and rebuilding profiles around it, did not fix the problem.

However, the private key for the developer cert was named differently from the certificate and the new one has a matching name.

I believe that Xcode might use the keychain or a similar method to the keychain, and has the same issues.